# Can an object's timestamp tag be viewed in JOSM?

Tags: josm

I have some data in JOSM that I would like to search and filter using the `timestamp:` expression. This is reasonably [well documented](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Search_function#Time-dependent).

The problem I have is that the timestamp reported by the History command for an object:

[image: History timestamp]

Differs from the timestamp stored with the data in the .osm file:

[image: .osm file timestamp]

I can see that in the case shown the difference is one hour, and is likely due to time zone (or daylight saving) differences, but the search functionality operates on the file timestamp, and the History command doesn't provide the time offset from UTC, making it hard to explore the timestamps in the data prior to writing the search expression.

Ideally I'd like to be able to view the timestamp stored with an object (as opposed to the server reported timestamp obtained from the History command) through the JOSM GUI, but can't see a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the *View > Advanced Info* command (Ctrl+I). This reports the object's timestamp.